# The meaning of "in the rack"

Tags: meaning, listening

On this [audio file](http://79.175.174.232/content/lessons/12/Intermediate2_2/unit_6/listening/listening.mp3), at 1:40, what does `in the rack` mean?

It's what I hear:

> I got three cars in the rack, it's all over the place down here, you know.

Source: The ILI English Series, Intermediate 2, Page 87

Comment: I think he said *on the rack*. I think he was talking about leaky fluid being all over the place. I'm not sure how that ties into cars being on the rack though.

Comment: At 1:40  I hear the male voice say "Er...".

Comment: Presumably he's lying to her so it might just be nonsense anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that it's probably *on the rack*, not *in the rack*.

*Rack* likely means either something like this, which is a car lifter for maintenance work:

[image: Car lifter for maintenance]

Or something like this, which is just a lifter to hold cars for storage:

[image: Car lifter for storage]

Being *on the rack* means "on a lifter", probably the first type since they're inside a mechanic's garage. From the context, a car radiator is apparently leaking around the three cars *on the rack*.

Note that there doesn't need to be a single rack for the mechanic to use *on the rack*, since it's similar to a construction like *on the road*. As long as the cars are in (a) rack(s), then he's saying something true about those cars. Whether he's telling the truth about the radiator in the lady's car is another thing altogether!

Comment: I'm not so sure about him telling the truth. He may have three cars in (or on) the rack, as you say, but it still sounds to me like he's trying to [take her for a ride](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/take-someone-for-a-ride).

Comment: @J.R. I'll amend my answer to specify that he's telling the truth about the rack––not her radiator!

Comment: I hesitated to start drawing too many conclusions. I wasn't sure if there was an important difference between a *lift* and a *rack* especially since that video was produced in the 70s or 80s.